# Why is my simplexml_load_string not allowing me store xml attributes in a php variable?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have a php variable ($output) that is holding a xml file with the following attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="tns:ns">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:transactionStatusResponse>
<MSISDN>254705680609</MSISDN>
<AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>
<MPESA_TRX_DATE>2016-05-21 10:57:43</MPESA_TRX_DATE>
<MPESA_TRX_ID>KEL7STGYEL</MPESA_TRX_ID>
<TRX_STATUS>Success</TRX_STATUS>
<RETURN_CODE>00</RETURN_CODE>
<DESCRIPTION>The service request is processed successfully.</DESCRIPTION>
<MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_ID/>
<ENC_PARAMS></ENC_PARAMS>
<TRX_ID>308e6137d9888ee8ead15c9577802947</TRX_ID>
</ns1:transactionStatusResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Now I am trying to put the individual xml attributes into php varibles but I seems not to be working. This is the what I am trying to use to extract the individual attributes

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($output);
$MPESA_TRX_ID= (string)$xml->MPESA_TRX_ID; 
$MSISDN = (string)$xml->MSISDN;
$AMOUNT = (string)$xml->AMOUNT;
```

Any workarounds this?

Comment: The XML is not valid. The opening tag for description is not proper. `<RETURN_CODE>00</RETURN_CODE><
DESCRIPTION>The service request is processed successfully.</DESCRIPTION>` Should be `<RETURN_CODE>00</RETURN_CODE><DESCRIPTION>The service request is processed successfully.</DESCRIPTION>`. There's a new line character in `DESCRIPTION` opening tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way how you can treat the xml from your question

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($output);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("ns1","tns:ns");

$xml2 = $xml->xpath("//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:transactionStatusResponse");
/*
foreach($xml2 as $item){
    var_dump($item->getName());
    browse($item);
    echo "\n";
}

function browse($elem)
{
    if($elem->children())
    {
        foreach($elem->children() as $child)
        {
            var_dump($child->getName());
            browse($child);
        }
    }
}

exit();
*/

$MPESA_TRX_ID = (string) $xml2[0]->MPESA_TRX_ID;
$MSISDN       = (string) $xml2[0]->MSISDN;
$AMOUNT       = (string) $xml2[0]->AMOUNT;

var_dump($MPESA_TRX_ID);
echo "\n";
var_dump($MSISDN);
echo "\n";
var_dump($AMOUNT);
```

output:

```
string(10) "KEL7STGYEL"

string(12) "254705680609"

string(2) "10"
```